# Angular - how to get result of a JSON object?

Tags: javascript, json, angular, api

I am trying to use the new Public API V2 CoinMarketCap, but I am trying some difficulty with this.

JSON:

https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/?limit=10

my model Coin:

```
export class Coins {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    symbol: string;
    rank: number;
    price_usd: number;
    price_btc: number;
    _24h_volume_usd: number;
    market_cap_usd: number;
    available_supply: number;
    total_supply: number;
    percent_change_1h: number;
    percent_change_24h: number;
    percent_change_7d: number;
    last_updated: number;
}
```

my service:

```
urlBase = 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/?limit=10';
getCoins() {
   return Observable
   .timer(0, 5000)
   .flatMap(() =>  this.http.get(this.urlBase))
   .pipe(
      map(res => res), 
      catchError(this.handleError)
    )
}
```

my component:

```
coins: Coins[];
getCoins() {
  this.coinsService.getCoins().subscribe(
    data => {
      this.coins = data;
    });
}
```

my html:

```
<div class="card card-inverse" *ngFor="let coin of coins">
```

output:

```
ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 
'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
```

any suggestion?

thank you

Comment: Can you show the definition for `Coin` please

Comment: Try to use *ngFor="let coin in coins".

Comment: Could this help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39761673/error-ngfor-only-supports-binding-to-iterables-such-as-arrays

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ERROR: NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39761673/error-ngfor-only-supports-binding-to-iterables-such-as-arrays)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the api data that you are showing, I see that you are assigning `this.coins` with the object but not an array. You should first convert it into an array and then assign it to `this.coins`.

```
getCoins() {
  this.coinsService.getCoins().subscribe(
    data => {
      this.coins = [];
      for(let key in data){
          this.coins.push(data[key]);
       }
    });
}
```

Or else you could also do this way to convert object to array.

```
getCoins() {
      this.coinsService.getCoins().subscribe(
        data => {
          this.coins = [];
          Object.keys(data).map((key)=>{ this.coins.push(data[key]) });
        });
}
```

In your service file

```
getCoins() {
    return this.http.get(this.urlBase).pipe(map(res => res = res.json()['data']))
}
```

Working [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-povnnx)

Comment: Hi Amit, thank you for your response.
In both I have output: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Comment: Initialize your coins as `coins : Coins[] = [];` during declaration.

Comment: @Michael If you don't initialize `coins` array with empty array `[]`, you will have to make use of temporary array and then assign it. It is best if you initialize inside the function itself, if not during declaration.

Comment: ok, I have no error, but nothing returns on the screen. How should it be in html?

Comment: Modify your service file accordingly, and i have added the demo for your reference.

Comment: Yes, it works for me !! Instead res = res.json() only  res = res

Answer (score 2):

Ok i tried your example and i see some problems with it. Not sure what you're trying to achieve with timer so ill keep it simple. The response im getting is this: `{ data: [], metadata: [] }`

So i assume that in your map you need to map like this `map(res => res.data)` to display the data property for example

I rewrote a simple example:

```
  getCoins() {
    const urlBase = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/?limit=10";
    this.http
      .get(urlBase)
      .pipe(map(res => res))
      .subscribe(res => console.log(res));
  }
```

To get the data property change the above map to `.pipe(map(res => res.data))`

To avoid ts error you can also type it:
`.pipe(map((res: { data: any; metadata: any }) => res.data))`

You will also need some aditional mapping for the data to match your Coin interface

I can help more if you cant find a way to do it ;)

Comment: Hi Megaklis, thank you for your response. I have this error: ERROR in src/app/service/coins.service.ts(34,22): error TS2339: Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Object'.

Comment: Thats because you haven't typed the data object. Try this:
`.pipe(map((res: { data: any; metadata: any }) => res.data))`

Any should be swapped for something more stable of course

Comment: error TS2339: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void'.

Comment: How about a screenshot or snippet?

Answer (score 1):

You got this error only because you are iterating an object. You need array of objects to iterate over.

Try below code in your mycomponent file.

```
getCoins() {
this.coinsService.getCoins().subscribe(
    data => {
        let coins = [];
        for (let key in data) {
            coins.push(data['key']);
        }
      this.coins = coins;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in service:

```
getCoins(): Observable<any> {
  const api = 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/?limit=10';
  return this.httpClient.get(api);    
}
```

in your component:

```
getCoins() {
    this.appService
      .getCoins()
      .subscribe(
        data => this.coins = data.data,
        error => console.log(error)
      );
  }

  coinKeys(coins) {
    return Object.keys(coins);
}
```

in template :

```
<tr *ngFor="let k of coinKeys(coins )">
    <td>{{ coins[k].id }}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.coins = data.json()` or you can use observable. 
in html `<div class="card card-inverse" *ngFor="let coin of coins | async">` 
in component

```
coins: Observable<Coin[]>;
```

`getCoins() {
  this.coins = this.coinsService.getCoins();
}`